# Install specific PHP version on Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: php, ubuntu

I need a bit of help. I have AWS EC2 server running on Ubuntu 16.04. My question is how do I install specific PHP version 7.3.12 ?

I have installed PHP and it ended in 7.3.14. Is this gonna be an issue if I have local environment with PHP 7.3.12 ? And how do we specifically install 7.3.12 on ubuntu server?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: you should use 7.3.14 in your development also. Because the main difference is only the bug fixing. There is no major feature changes or deprecation between these two.

Comment: So whatever you built on 7.3.12 will run on 7.3.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not have any issue between PHP 7.3.12 and 7.3.14.

A version is split in 3 parts, 7(for main version).3(for current minor version).12(for bugfixes).

Do not try to exec php code on two differents main version 5.0 / 7.0 because of many big changes.

Also there is no many changes in minor version but still, you can have some differents behavior.

And the last one for bugfixes, you should not worry about.
For a complete list of change you can find the changelog : https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#PHP_7_3

Bugfixes version are release all life of supported version, for exemple PHP 7.3 will have security fixes until 6 Dec 2021.
For actual list, see : https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

---

For your other question, you can install another version of php with major an minor (like php 7.2 or php 7.3) in ubuntu and change the path of the php exec command.
But you can't choose (Not sure at 100%) between php 7.3.12 and 7.3.14 because it's bugfixes and it's just a update.